# Cannot call javascript's async functions from nashorn java

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I want to call a javascript function like the following from java using nashorn

```
async function testSample() {    
    for (var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
        await sample[i]();
    }    
}
```

So it will execute all the functions in the sample variablel. But I am getting the following error

```
Expected ; but found function
async function testSample()() {
  ^ in <eval> at line number 8 at column number 6
```

Is there support for async functions on nashorn?

Any work around to solve this?

Comment: put a `;` before async then try

Comment: @AyushGupta: That's not going to fix the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` is defined in ECMAScript 2017; Nashorn currently only supports ECMAScript 5.1.

Therefore, you cannot directly call this code from Nashorn. You could try to  rewrite it using `Promise`s, or maybe compile it down to ES5 with something like babel.

Comment: So there is no way to call async methods.

Comment: @venkat Not from Nashorn, no. You can try to rewrite the code using `Promises` or maybe transpile it to ES5 with babel.

Comment: Can Rhino do this? - @ohlec

Comment: @venkat I don't think so. Rhino supports JavaScript 1.7, which is Mozilla's versioning system. I'm not sure what standard exactly it corresponds to, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't support `async`/`await`